# How to compare a integer in tuple in a list, to another integer in another tuple in another list in one dictionary?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

For example, I have:

`>>>a = {'dog': [('cute', 10, 20)], 'cat': [('nice', 12, 11)], 'fish':[('hate', 1, 3)]}`

Expect to return `'dog'` because the sum of the integers at index 1 and 2 is 30, which is greater than the sum of integers for cat and fish.

If I don't use import, is there a easy way to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Just use `max` with a custom key.

```
>>> a = {'dog': [('cute', 10, 20)], 'cat': [('nice', 12, 11)], 'fish':[('hate', 1, 3)]}
>>> max(a, key=lambda x: sum(a[x][0][1:]))
'dog'
```

Each `x` is a key in the dictionary, so we're getting the `sum` of elements `1` and onward in the first element of this key `x`'s value in `a`.

Comment: `print timeit.timeit(
"""a = {'dog': [('cute', 10, 20)], 'cat': [('nice', 12, 11)], 'fish':[('hate', 1, 3)]}

max_key = a.keys()[0]
max_sum=0
for key in a.keys():
    cur_sum = sum(a[key][0][1:])
    if cur_sum>max_sum:
        max_sum = cur_sum
        max_key = key
""",number=10000
)` gave `0.0300233601695` on an average and

`print timeit.timeit(
"""a = {'dog': [('cute', 10, 20)], 'cat': [('nice', 12, 11)], 'fish':[('hate', 1, 3)]}
max(a, key=lambda x: sum(a[x][0][1:]))""",number=10000
)` gave `0.0265969282814` which makes this much better and pythonic :)

Comment: Is there another way to do it even without using lambda?

Answer (score 2):

`print max(a.items(), key=lambda (key, val): sum(val[0][1:]))[0] # dog`

Answer (score 2):

Tigerhawk nailed it, my solution if someone wants a traditional non-pythonic soln -

```
a = {'dog': [('cute', 10, 20)], 'cat': [('nice', 12, 11)], 'fish':[('hate', 1, 3)]}

max_key = a.keys()[0]
max_sum=0
for key in a.keys():
    cur_sum = sum(a[key][0][1:])
    if cur_sum>max_sum:
        max_sum = cur_sum
        max_key = key

print max_key
```

Comment: Does max_key = a.keys()[0] support indexing?

Comment: @CrystalTran max_key was initialized with the first key in the dict. doing a.keys() outputs a list of keys so I can access that like a list